# Problems with proving P. Hall theorem for finitely presented groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've problems with proving P. Hall theorem about finitely presented groups. I would like to find a proof different from the one  written in Robinson textbook.

I can't prove  this theorem and in particular the property of being extension closed.

I mean: if $ N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $N$ is finitely presented and the quotient $G/N$ is finitely presented, why should be the group $G$ finitely presented? Can someone help me? Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: if you want that it is different from Robnson 's book, you should write it.